# Assigning remaining work to product backlog in DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using Microsoft DevOps (on prem) and would like to track the remaing work in the product backlog items rather than tasks.
Any way to populate team capacity, moving this value from activity to product backlog?

I say "remaining work" because I saw this is the value populates the work details and capacity but any field would work for me.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below help you? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Thank you, the answer helped even though looks like I can't achieve it in this way so I'll do it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any way to populate team capacity, moving this value from activity to product backlog?

I am afraid there is no such out of box way to do this.

As the document [Scrum process work item types and workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/scrum-process-workflow?view=azure-devops), we could to know:

> To gain insight into a portfolio of features, scenarios, or user
>   experiences, product owners and program managers can map PBIs and bugs
>   to features. When teams work in sprints, **they define tasks which
>   automatically link to PBIs and bugs**.

[image]

So, the Backlog Item's "`Effort`" field will calculate the effort based on the summation of its child Task items "`Remaining Work`".

For example:

1. A new Backlog Item is created. The "Effort" field is left empty.
2. A new child task for the previous Backlog item is created, the
   "Remaining Work" field is set as 5.
3. The "Effort" field of the Backlog Item created in step 1 is
   automatically updated to 5.

On the other hand, from the document [Update and monitor your Taskboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/task-board?view=azure-devops):

> Your Taskboard provides a visualization of flow and status of each
>   sprint task. With it, you can focus on the status of backlog items as
>   well as work assigned to each team member. **It also summarizes the
>   total amount of remaining work to complete for a task or within a
>   column.**

So, Scrum does not consider the time spent on the Sprint Backlog. It only care about the remaining work and time variables.

Besides, there is an extension [VSTS Rollup](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=canarysautomationspvtltd.vstsrollup), which could rollup of efforts of Task Work Items to parent level items like PBI, Stories, Feature, Epic, etc. **But** it only But it is only compatible with Azure DevOps Services.

Check the [similar thread](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/26551/how-can-the-backlog-items-effort-field-be-auto-calculated-in-azure-devops) for some details.

Hope this helps.